# Changing a 7 day calendar to a 5 day calendar

Tags: javascript, html, date, calendar

I'm looking to change my current 7 day calendar to a 5 day calendar.
My 7 day goes from Sunday to Saturday, I'm looking to change it to Monday to Friday.

From what i've picked up theres two main methods of doing this:

```
-Hide both Sunday and Saturday columns using css.
-Rerun script to exclude Sunday and Saturday, calculating the dates again.
```

I have looked at both ways and just can't get my head round how it will work, I'm looking for some help.

**createCalendar()**

```
calendarString = '';
calendarString += '<table width="100%" height="425" data-role="table" border="1" bordercolor="#c0c0c0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
calendarString += '<tr>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sun<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Mon<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Tue<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Wed<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Thu<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Fri<\/td>';
calendarString += '<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\" align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=\"40\" height=\"22\">Sat<\/td>';
calendarString += '<\/tr>';
thisDate == 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
{
    calendarString += '<tr>';
        for (var x = 1; x <= 7; x++) 
            {
                daycounter = (thisDate - firstDay)+1;
                thisDate++;
                if ((daycounter > numbDays) || (daycounter < 1)) 
                    {
                        calendarString += '<td align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#888888\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">&nbsp;<\/td>';
                    } 
                    else 
                        {
                            if (checkevents(daycounter,monthNum,yearNum,i,x) || ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)))
                                {
                                    if ((todaysDay == x) && (todaysDate == daycounter) && (todaysMonth == monthNum)) 
                                        {
                                            tempweek = i;
                                            tempdayofweek = x;
                                            calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#AAFFAA\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<\/td>';
                                        }
                                else    
                                    {
                                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFC8\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" onClick=showevents(' + daycounter + ',' + monthNum + ',' + yearNum + ',' + i + ',' + x + ')>' + daycounter + '<div id="amountevent" style="padding-left:5px;max-height:8px; height:8px; width:30px; max-width:30px;white-space: nowrap;">' + displayeventnumber(daycounter, monthNum, yearNum) + '</div><\/td>';


                                    }
                            } 
                            else 
                                {
                                    calendarString += '<td style=\"vertical-align: top;\" bgcolor=\"#f9f9f9\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\">' + daycounter + '<\/td>';         
                                }
                        }
                }
            calendarString += '<\/tr>';
        }
    calendarString += '<\/table>';
    var object=document.getElementById('calendar');
    object.innerHTML= calendarString;
    thisDate = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS solution is esier (both for your messy code and the problem of jumping 2 days), but modifying JS should be better.

They're first and last  elements, so you can do like this:

```
table td:first-child, table td:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

Problem: last-child doesn't work on older browsers (IE<9). 
Solution: jQuery works cross-browser:

```
$('table td:first-child, table td:last-child').remove()
```

Note: Are you sure you mean `thisDate == 1;` ? Or a single =?

Comment: I tried working with something similar, ill give this a try but the plan is to be able to switch between both 5 day and 7 day calendar. and this thats ment to be just a single "=".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything in inner for loop works as advertised, you could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    thisDate++ //Sunday
    calendarString += '<tr>'

    for (var x = 2; x <= 6; x++) {
        //all of that inner for loop code
    }

    calendarString += '</tr>'
    thisDate++ //Saturday
}
```

Also: `thisDate == 1` should be: `thisDate = 1` up at the top before the initial for loop.

Comment: spot on my friend, also I ran into another little bug, my calendar always thinks that the last day is the 28th??

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But im going to use the css method. easier implemented.